# How to return back to parent activity from child activity in ActivityGroup?

Tags: android

I've implemented a TabActivity Which has 4 Tabs, one of the tab is `ParentActivity` when I go to this tab, there is a button which says `Go To Child` when I click on this button I'm able to go to the child activity as follows:

```
 /****************** ON BUTTON CLICK ******************/
 Intent childView = new Intent(v.getContext(), ChildActivity.class);
 replaceContentView("child_view", childView );
 //ParentActivity.this.finish();
 /****************************************************/

 public void replaceContentView(String activityID, Intent activityIntent) {
 View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(activityID,activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView();
 this.setContentView(view);
 }
```

Now I want to come back to `ParentActivity` when I click on the Button which says `Go To Parnt` in ChildActivity. How do I do this, I tried so many examples but I didn't get it. I want my tabs must be in all the activities. I've included sample activity image.[image]

Comment: You can use manifest tags and specify a parent activity. `android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"` This will work for back navigation. However if you want that on a button, just pass the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Start `Child Activity` like:

```
 Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), Contact.class);
 TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
 parentActivity.startChildActivity("Contact", edit);
```

And Implement back button click on `Child Activity` like:

```
back_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
        parentActivity.onBackPressed();

        }
    });
```

And implement `onBackPressed()` on your `TabGroupActivity` like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try{
        Log.i("TabGroup", "Current on BackPressed called: ");
        int length = mIdList.size();
        Log.i("TabGroup", "Current ArrayList Size(): "+length);
        if (length > 1) {

            Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(
                    mIdList.get(length - 1));

            Log.i("TabGroup", "Current Last Activity"+current);

            current.finish();
        } else {
            MakeExitDialog();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And also add `startChildActivity(....)` in your `TabGroupActivity`

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
    // LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    int count = mIdList.size() - 1;
    for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--) {
        // System.out.println("Activity "+i+":::"+mIdList.get(i));
    }

    // System.out.println("Activity Started");
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        mIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}
```

**Update:** make your main `TabGroupActivity` like:

```
  public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

private ArrayList<String> mIdList;
public static TabGroupActivity tabgrp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mIdList == null)
        mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int length = mIdList.size();
        Log.i("TabGroupActivity", "ArrayList Size(): "+length);
}



@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {

    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    int index = mIdList.size() - 1;

    if (index < 1) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
    mIdList.remove(index);
    index--;
    String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
    Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
    Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
    setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
}


public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
    // LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    int count = mIdList.size() - 1;
    for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--) {
        // System.out.println("Activity "+i+":::"+mIdList.get(i));
    }

    // System.out.println("Activity Started");
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    if (window != null) {
        mIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try{
        Log.i("TabGroup", "Current on BackPressed called: ");
        int length = mIdList.size();
        Log.i("TabGroup", "Current ArrayList Size(): "+length);
        if (length > 1) {

            Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(
                    mIdList.get(length - 1));

            Log.i("TabGroup", "Current Last Activity"+current);

            current.finish();
        } else {

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I just tried the code which you have posted above, may I know what is `mIdList` and `MakeExitDialog()` I've a `TabActivity` as `public class TabCollectionActivity extends TabActivity{}` as, you told I've implemented `onBackPressed()` and `startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent)` in this Activity, but I didn't get what is `mIdList` I'm getting error here.

Comment: wait for a while i post main `TabGroupActivity`

Comment: Hi.. I tried your updated code but it doesn't work for me. I've total 4 Activities say `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and a Tab Activity `TabCollection` which `extends TabActivity` I've Defined all other 4 activities inside TabActivity, and there is a Child Activity whose Parent is Activity `B`, Now From `B` in need to switch to `Child` and vice verse. But Tab's should appear in child activity as well.